# Broken Find Function in my Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why this find function in a DL List I am writing isn't working. The issue is that the comparison between tempNode->data and s is failing. Despite the data being equal the comparison is evaluating to false. Anyone know why?

```
bool DoublyLinkedList::find(string& s)
{
if(empty())
    return false;
else
{
    Node* tempNode = head;
    do{
        if(*(tempNode->data) == s)
        {
            return true;
        }
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    } while(tempNode != NULL);
    return false;
}
}
class Node
    {
        public:
            Node* next;
            Node* prev;
            string* data;
            Node(){next = NULL; prev = NULL; data = NULL;};
            ~Node(){delete prev; delete next; delete data; next =  NULL; prev = NULL; data = NULL;};
    };
```

Comment: You're comparing pointers, not strings. Also, your entire code is a car wreck in slow motion. Can you spot a problem with the very first statement in the function?

Comment: What is the reason for doing `string* theSong = new string(s);`?

Comment: Can anyone roll-back the latest edit? It completely breaks the question.

Comment: I removed the dynamically allocated string. Can't get the comparison to evaluate to true still.

Comment: What is `tempNode->data`? Key bits of code are missing.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I added my Node Class now.

Comment: You'll probably run into runtime errors with that destructor. You're basically deleting every node twice.

Comment: I was under the impression you were supposed to set a pointer to null after you delete it as good practice.

Comment: That indeed. But when you `delete next` in the destructor of a node, the node whose destructor runs is already deleted. The `delete prev` in the next nodes destructor then tries to delete the previous, already deleted node again.

Comment: @CodeManiak The evaluation still doesn't work? That error lies someone else, the code we helped you to correct does work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b23b9d5e812a19fb

Comment: My destructor on the DLList was the issue. It wasn't properly popping all the nodes off of the list! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that you have a memory leak, you seem to be comparing pointers here:

```
if(tempNode->data == theSong) { .... }
```

You probably need something like

```
if(*(tempNode->data) == s) { .... }
```

You really do not need the dynamically allocated pointer bound to `theSong`. Also, the parameter to `find` should be a `const` reference:

```
bool DoublyLinkedList::find(const string& s)
//                          ^^^^^
```

In general, you should decouple traversing a linked list from finding an element in it. Otherwise you will find yourself replicating the traversal code bugs and all in many places.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm writing this according to UML specs so I can't change the public interface of this class. But you're right.

Comment: @CodeManiak so your list is not traversable in its public interface? Some interface!

Comment: All I meant is that I can't put const in front of the parameter for the project I'm working on.

Comment: @CodeManiak Some project, then :-) To have a non-const reference for the input parameter is patently absurd.

Comment: Go ahead and mock me but I'm going to figure this out and get an A in this class.

Comment: @CodeManiak Sorry, I am not mocking you. I am commenting on the project. Good luck with it, but beware it doesn't seem to be teaching you good C++.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you pointing that out. It's an important factor to be aware of especially in case a google search lands someone here.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the addresses of two different string objects. Use [`string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) instead or compare the values.

Also, why do you create a new string from the already existing string?

`if (s.compare(tempNode->data) == 0)` or `s == *(tempNode->data)` is probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to write this as a comment but I don't have enough reputations to do so.

You should definitely not compare address of string but compare the string itself (at least in your case). Also beware of the string case comparison and make sure that you specify if you want to do case sensitive or insensitive comparison.

Besides that you don't need to create a temporary string object and you can use the formal parameter itself that is passed to the function.
Even if you ever wanted to create temporary variables then you should consider using shared_ptr or unique_ptr to avoid memory leaks.

Stephan T Lavavej has an excellent talk recently on Going Native and I would recommend you to watch it. Right now the website is down and I can add link to it when the site comes back again.

I would also make the formal parameter as const to make sure that you don't accidentally modify the input parameter.

Comment: This is the video that I talked above - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler